# Regex scientific notation

Tags: python, regex

I need to float the following strings that represent scientific notation values without the exponent:

```
'-1.366-6'
'1.366-6'
'-1.366+6'
'1.366+6'
'-1.25-10'
```

I need to insert an 'e' before the final + or -

```
'-1.366e-6'
'1.366e-6'
'-1.366e+6'
'1.366e+6'
'-1.25e-10'
```

How can I use regex to achieve this?

Comment: You need to show us that what you have tried for solve you problem so far! if you want to get a desire answer for such simple task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  use `re.sub`,

```
re.sub(r'(?=[-+][^-+]*$)', 'e', string)
```

The above regex matches the boundary which was followed by last `+` or `-` character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eY0yR9/1)

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['-1.366-6', '1.366-6', '-1.366+6', '1.366+6', '-1.25-10']
>>> for i in l:
        print(re.sub(r'(?=[-+][^-+]*$)', 'e', i))


-1.366e-6
1.366e-6
-1.366e+6
1.366e+6
-1.25e-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
re.sub(r'(?=[-+][^-+]*$)', 'e', '+1.3666')
```

returns `'e+1.3666'`. If you'd like it to return `'+1.3666'`, then you could use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[+-])', 'e', text)
```

instead.

---

```
import re

tests = [
('-1.366-6', '-1.366e-6'),
('1.366-6',  '1.366e-6' ),
('-1.366+6', '-1.366e+6'),
('1.366+6',  '1.366e+6' ),
('-1.25-10', '-1.25e-10'),
('+1.366', '+1.366'),
]

for text, expected in tests:
    result = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[+-])', 'e', text)
    print(result)
    assert result == expected
```

yields

```
-1.366e-6
1.366e-6
-1.366e+6
1.366e+6
-1.25e-10
+1.366
```

The pattern `(?<=\d)(?=[+-])` means

```
(?<=      # match if preceded by 
\d        # a digit
 )    
(?=       # match if followed by
[+-]      # a literal plus or minus sign
 )
```